GUI axes not lining in Matlab app designer
Can someone explain to me why THE BODE PLOT is not lining in my app designer? As you can see the magnitude plot is smaller than the phase one

I'm very new to matlab
I already tried edit some inspector and it didn't solve it
Thanks for the answer
